# WebRTC multicast (one-to-many)

Tags: multicast, webrtc

Hi I have questions about WebRTC.

I would like create one-to-many (1:N) connection with MCU server (because stream from source is too big (CPU,bandwidth...)), but I don't know how can I do that, exists some project for this? I found only EasyRTC, Licode etc. but I guess that is just for videoconferencing (many-to-many).
Thank you very much

Comment: You should show what you have tried; SO exists to help you with *specific* questions about programming problems, not generic "how to" advice.

Comment: Ok, thank you, so where can I ask?

Comment: bad moderation, this question was fine.

Answer (score 27):

Try WebRTC [one-way broadcasting](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/webrtc-broadcasting/) and [one-to-many broadcasting](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/broadcast/) experiments. [Source codes](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment) are available as well.

In **peer-to-peer** scenario; [**max limit**](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/webrtcpedia/) for peer connections per single chrome instance (tab/window) is **256**.

Obviously, there will be [huge bandwidth/CPU usage](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/RTP-usage.html) when number of peer connections increases.

A simple solution can be peer-to-server model (**peer**-to-**media server**-to-**all other peers**).

Comment: "A simple solution can be peer-to-server model (peer-to-media server-to-all other peers)." But this is problem, because I can't find any project like this, webrtc-experiment (one-to-many) is based without sever (media server), right? Thank you very much

Comment: What kind of Media server can be used? Exists some source codes for this kind of model, I mean peer-to-server.

Comment: There are many media servers like TokeBox's "Montis", or Asterisk, Kamailio, or 3rd party servers like big-blue-button or ngvx. I prefer "Asterisk" over 3rd party media servers!! I'll add a demo on my Github repo in next few weeks.

Comment: Hi @MuazKhan , I've seen your work at your GitHub repo and  is Great.
Do you know any good tutorial about how to video broadcasting (for web apps) using Asterisk? I really will appreciate it !!!

Comment: have you finally made it ?