# Want to configure a Live Audio + Video streaming server

Tags: audio, video, streaming, live-streaming

I want to configure live Audio Video streaming server.
I need to broadcast live proceedings from a Community hall to number of connected users through a web site.

I am rather confused as to what is the best way to achieve this? Users are maximum of 500. 
Will i need a dedicated media server for streaming Audio / Video ?

If yes what is the best one available, or anyone have used it then it would be great as i could get some concrete information.

I Will be needing a web server to host the community page. Where user can log in and see the videos embedded in the web page. Will the same server can act as both Media and Web Server ?

I googled lots of things regarding this but could not find a clear cut information on how to set up the things.

I came across a media server called Icecast but could not find proper information on its implementation.

Anyone having knowledge in this regard, Please guide me through this.

Thanks & Regards,
LazyCoder7.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056683/webrtc-multicast-one-to-many

Comment: Can the post in the above link can be helpful in the scenario I mentioned. I also request @Muaz Khan to please guide me a bit because I am getting really confused by all the various possibilities and options.