# One to many groups calling web app using WebRTC. I have some confusion about the call connection and switch stream

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have already seen this question [WebRTC multicast (one-to-many)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056683/webrtc-multicast-one-to-many)

But I have only two simple questions.

Q1. How to connect one to many WebRTC peer connections.
Do we have to create different offers for each peer?

Explanation Q1: Teacher has to group call for their students.
Will the teacher has to create the WebRTC offer for each student for a call connection?

Q2. Do we have to create the offer again if we want to switch voice call to video call or vice versa the media stream?

Explanation Q2: Can we add new Track on ongoing call?

Comment: 1: Yes. 2: No, use`replaceTrack`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jib . But I want to switch between voice call to video call or vice versa. Is it possible without creating new offer?

Comment: Use `sender.replaceTrack(null)` to temporarily turn off sending of a track without renegotiation.

Comment: @jib .. It works sender.replaceTrack(null) or sender.replaceTrack(track) when I already have same kind of track in senders array.

Suppose I started a call only with an audio track and want to add a video track. Then sender.replaceTrack(track) not work where sender has null track in senders array.
I think in that case I need to renegotiation?

Comment: Right. Use `addTransceiver("video")` and `addTransceiver("audio")` to add both upfront, then replace in tracks as needed.